# RDD data into multiple rows in spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a fixed width text file(sample) with data

> 2107abc2018abn2019gfh

where all the rows data are combined as single row
I need to read the textfile and split data according fixed row length=7
and generate multiple rows and store it in RDD.

```
2107abc

2018abn

2019gfh
```

where `2107` is one column and `abc` is one more column

will the logic will be applicable for huge data file like 1 GB or more?

Comment: You can try map operation to split each row into multiple arrays. Like Array(Array()). Then do flatMap to get the Array() with one dimension each row.

Comment: this is a similar question to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031127/how-to-read-a-fixed-character-length-format-file-in-spark but they assume here that the file contains multiple lines.

Comment: You can split your file to multiple lines first then apply the suggested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm amusing that you have `RDD[String]` and you want to extract both columns from your data. First you can split the line at length 7 and then again at 4. You will get your columns separated. Below is the code for same.

```
//creating a sample RDD from the given string
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("""2107abc2018abn2019gfh"""))

//Now first split at length 7 then again split at length 4 and create dataframe
val res = rdd.flatMap(_.grouped(7).map(x=>x.grouped(4).toSeq)).map(x=> (x(0),x(1)))

//print the rdd
res.foreach(println)

//output
//(2107,abc)
//(2018,abn)
//(2019,gfh)
```

If you want you can also convert your RDD to dataframe for further processing.

```
//convert to DF
val df = res.toDF("col1","col2")

//print the dataframe
df.show
//+----+----+
//|col1|col2|
//+----+----+
//|2107| abc|
//|2018| abn|
//|2019| gfh|
//+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers..i too got the output.